# "bash: gulp: command not found" after installation

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, gulp

In **cmder** i run:

"***npm install -g gulp***", then "***gulp***" which gets "***bash: gulp: command not found***".

I've added:

"***npm install gulp-cli -g"***, same error.

I've read specific user mentioning in the path may be the case, but when I run:

***"npm config get prefix"***, I get "***A:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\local***" which is supposingly not the case since no specific user's being mentioned.

I've read i should go "*My computer -> properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables"* and change the User's variable ***path*** to "***C:\Users%user_name%\AppData\Roaming\npm***", but there already was this line. I've only moved it up above the others which did not lead to any changes as a result.

I've been uninstalling gulp via "npm uninstall gulp" and then installing again. Not the case. So I don't know where else to go with it from here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step:
This is for linux/mac but might be helpful

1. npm i and check the version of node. Some times gulp doesnt run in the latest version. Try running nvm use v8.16.0 or nvm use v10
2. source ~/.bash_profile
3. npm i -g gulp
4. gulp

It should work!